# Searching for a word on a page after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

By using JavaScript or jQuery, I am trying to figure out if a word, say "casablanca", is available on the page?

The page I am working on makes an ajax call which changes the content of the page. So I am supposed to search for the word "casablanca" after the ajax call.

The best way I have found so far is:

```
window.find('casablanca');
```

But this code highlights the word, which is something I don't want.

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the behaviour you expect instead of highlighting it?

Comment: @Anchor he said "figure out if word exists on the page, without highlighting it" so I assume he just wants a bool

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML.match('casablanca')`

Comment: Hi Ozan, if you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and programmatic way to determine whether the current HTML page contains a specific keyword:

```
function pageContains(str) {
    return document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(str) > -1;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shj4LwqL/

---

Please be aware that the above code searches for the keyword in the page's `body` tag, so if you have your JavaScript in the page body, and your keyword is written as a string in your JavaScript, then you will get a false positive. If you want to search within a specific element instead, you can use the following variant:

```
function elementContains(el, str) {
    return el.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(str) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

searches for only in content, not in tags and so on:

```
function searchInPage(val) {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

    for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        var node = allElements[i].firstChild;

        //Is it a text node?
        if(node !== null && node.nodeType === 3) {
            if(node.nodeValue == val) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**untested** it shows you the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.contents()` , `.is()` to return `Boolean` ; substitute `.filter()` for `.is()` to return element containing selected text , if `true` , `false` if node not found having selected text

```js
var res = $("body").contents().is(function(i, el) {
  return $(":contains(casablanca)").is(el)
}); console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">

  <p>By using JavaScript or jQuery, I am trying to figure out if a word, say "casablanca", is available on the page?</p>

  <p>The page I am working on makes an ajax call which changes the content of the page. So I am supposed to search for the word "casablanca" after the ajax call.</p>

  <p>The best way I have found so far is:</p>

  <pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="pln">window</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">find</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="str">'casablanca'</span><span class="pun">);</span></code></pre>

  <p>But this code highlights the word, which is something I don't want.</p>

  <p>Is there a better way?</p>

  <p>Thank you!</p>
</div>
```